# No module name found

Tags: python-2.7, py2exe

I had created a python file which will pull the data from app dynamics for which i had imported the package from appd.request import AppDynamicsClient
it is working fine but now i want to convert it into .exe for which i am using py2exe in py2exe i am trying to include the package appdynamics but it is giving error package not found

```
from appd.request import AppDynamicsClient
from matplotlib.dates import date2num
import matplotlib.dates as dates
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 
import requests
```

these are the packages i am importing in main file which i am trying to convert it into .exe file
setup.py file

```
from distutils.core import setup
from distutils.core import setup
import py2exe

setup(console=['AD_API.py'],
 options = {
    "py2exe": {

        'packages' :['requests','AppDynamicsClient','matplotlib']
    }
}
```

)

**ERROR MESSAGE:
ImportError: No module named AppDynamicsClient**

Comment: have you tried full path like: `appd.request.AppDynamicsClient` or just `appd.request`

Comment: thnx for the reply i had tried this also but not working